# US Census Block Internal Points

Tags: geospatial, us-census

I am trying to get a list of all ~11 million 2010 census blocks' internal points (latitudes and longitudes assigned by the census to be used as approximate locations for each block). I can't for the life of me find these anywhere without downloading the entire polygon geodatabase! I finally broke down and downloaded that, but at ~6 petabytes, I don't have the storage to unzip and work with the file. Does anyone know of a source for internal points ONLY before I whip something up to download and process each geodatabase by state or county?

Comment: Why do you think such a dataset exists?

Comment: fgregg, I should have mentioned that flat files with basic information including internal points are distributed for lots of census geometries as "Gazetteer Files". The Census website does not link to a Gazetteer file for census blocks, but in the past I have found third party websites, such as NHGIS and Social Explorer, that distribute data not easily retrieved directly from the Census.

Comment: are these sometimes referred to as crosswalks?

Comment: pretty sure i found it, but its not 11 million records. where/why do you think its 11 million?

Comment: Thanks, Albert. I got 11.155 million from the wikipedia article on census blocks (that includes PR). I looked through the crosswalk/relationship file descriptions and didn't see columns for internal points. What have you found?

Comment: i downloaded the 2010 gazetteer files and opened it up...it only has 33000 rows...two columns are lat/lon for internal points. if thats right, i'll post it as an answer

Comment: Hmm that seems like too few, could that be for census tracts or some geography larger than census blocks? Or possibly for a single state or county? I didn't see a link to Gazetteer files for blocks on the census website. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: ah then its this https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/gazetteer2010.html#anch_334

Comment: I couldn't find an official source but I think http://gis.drcog.org/datacatalog/sites/default/files/shapefiles/BLOCK_CENTROIDS_2010.zip or http://freegisdata.org/record/urn:uuid:f4cf9edf-ab68-4a6e-8589-9136379ce324-DRCOGPUB:block_centroids_2010/ is what you seek. I've done "work" in this area and used blockgroups (not blocks) because block-level data is not released.

Comment: This is intriguing as hell. I can't wait until someone wikileaks the 2020 ACS census data on a census block level. What a joy that would be. Where are those polygons!?? lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `intptlon` and `intptlat` fields of the census bureau's summary files contain the center of every census block nationwide.  there's some pretty straightforward R code to download and import these files here:

https://github.com/davidbrae/swmap/blob/master/how%20to%20map%20the%20consumer%20expenditure%20survey.R

Comment: Thank you! I didn't expect the SF1 file to have geographic information and this is smaller/faster than downloading Tiger files.